# Typescript prefers importing relative import instead of path alias

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, import

Is there a way to force TS to use a path alias for imports if there is one available? (I use VSCode)

```
import { ApiError } from '../../../../libs/shared/src'; // This is imported by default
//import { ApiError } from '@rita/shared'; // I want this


const err: ApiError = { /* ... */ };
```

Ts config extract

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": ".",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "target": "ES2017",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "paths": {
            "@rita/helpers": ["libs/helpers/src/index.ts"],
            "@rita/maps": ["libs/maps/src/index.ts"],
            "@rita/rxjs": ["libs/rxjs/src/index.ts"],
            "@rita/shared": ["libs/shared/src/index.ts"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a TypeScript feature. Are you talking about something your IDE does (adding imports for you)? If so, which IDE?

Comment: You might be right... I use VSCode

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I'm pretty sure this used to work, but somehow it is broken now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it following this github issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/59815

Inside Visual Studio Code, go to `Settings` by typing <kbd>Ctrl + ,</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>CMD + ,</kbd> (Mac), then using the Search settings box, search for importModuleSpecifier, then select from TypeScript section non-relative.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I've had this issue in VSCode. The problem was I have set `importModuleSpecifier` to relative in settings.json. Setting this to default fixed my issue.

```
{
   // remove this or set to "shortest"
  "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem and I think this issue is related to this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47053.

For me, the absolute import, eg. `@/components/` is always second option, no matter which setting I choose.

The solution mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72029899 did not work for me as well, and I also don't want to change anything about my `index.ts` import/exports.

What seems to help is to set paths to use `./` instead of `@/` and use `"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative"` setting in VSCode, but it feels really strange since it looks like a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

For the config in `paths` object, try this:

```json
{
  "@rita/helpers/*": ["libs/helpers/src/*"],
  "@rita/maps/*": ["libs/maps/src/*"],
  "@rita/rxjs/*": ["libs/rxjs/src/*"],
  "@rita/shared/*": ["libs/shared/src/*"]
}
```

Perhaps referencing the `index.ts` directly isn't right, as it's not a path, but a file. And the wildcard might be important too.

FYI: I'm referencing the [TSConfig Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths).

Comment: But my index does export everything it needs.

Comment: This does change how I import things and sadly does not solve it.